# Given $\{\log_ab \mid a,b\in \mathbb N, \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1,a,b≥3\}$ does the sum of any two $\log_ab$ form an irrational or rational number?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, logarithms

Given $\{\log_ab \mid a,b\in \mathbb N, \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1,a,b≥3\}$ does the sum of any two $\log_ab$ form an irrational or rational number?

I know that $\log_ab$ is irrational, but does the sum of any two $\log_ab$ form an irrational or rational number?

e.g. Is $\{\log_3(5)+log_7(11) \in \mathbb Q\}$ or is $\{\log_3(5)+\log_7(11) \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q\}$.

Comment: Thank you for adding the question in words. But do you rather want to ask if the set $\{\,\log_a b\mid a,b\in\mathbb N, \gcd(a,b)=1, a,b\ge 3\,\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ under addition?

Comment: Try verifying the conditions for the group. Is it closed? Is it associative? Does it have an identity? What about inverses?

Comment: @Hagen - Yes I did not state the problem correctly. You are correct, what I was looking for was not is log_ab is group, but is log_ab closed under addition.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what's being asked. Are you wondering whether sums such as $\log_3(5) + \log_7(11)$ always come out irrational? Or whether they can always be put back into the form $\log_a(b)$ with $a,b$ integers satisfying $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$ and $a,b \geq 3$?

Comment: I am asking if $log_3(5)+log_7(1)) always comes out irrational.

Comment: There are many unsolved problems about irrationality. This may be one of them.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** What is the identity of this operation? Is it an element in your set?

Comment: Unfortunately, OP's edit to the question has made this a non-answer.

Answer (score -1):

No, for instance,

$log_5(7) - 2log_{25}(7) = \frac{log(7)}{log(5)} - 2\frac{log(7)}{log(25)} = \frac{log(7)}{log(5)} - \frac{2log(7)}{2log(5)} = \frac{log(7)}{log(5)}-\frac{log(7)}{log(5)} = 0$

Comment: I see that a,b=5,7 for the first term. What are a and b for the second term?

Comment: sorry a=25, b=7 fixed for clarity.